# Set permission to directory at runtime scala spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a directory from within my spark code on HDFS and writing a file in it. but while writing it is failing with below error.

```
Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, 
inode="/root/test/_temporary/0":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
```

How do we set permission on the directory at runtime in scala ?

**UPDATE**

I'm using these commands to grant permission on the created directory.

```
  dir.canExecute()
  dir.canRead()
  dir.canWrite()

  dir.setWritable(true, false)
  dir.setReadable(true,false)
  dir.setExecutable(true, false)
```

Comment: How did you create that directory? what do you get when you execute `dir.canWrite()`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks philantrovert to taking a look at this but I realized that even though I was successful in creating directory at runtime and dir.canWrite() returned true, this was on EMR, directory was created on the server but Spark was actually trying to write to HDFS where no such folder existed. -:)